# MS Word document with MathType formulas to HTML

Tags: microsoft-word, html, mathtype

I'm tasked with converting an MS Word document (*.docx) to an HTML file. This word document contains many formulas written in MathType.
Here's a dummy text similar to that of the Word document:

[image]

I tried saving the document as a webpage but ended up with this:

[image]

The formulas was converted to low resolution images and looked pretty unappealing.

Is there a way to achieve a satisfactory result without manually recreating the original document in HTML?

I must admit I'm a complete novice in this area.

Comment: [[1]] Convert to PDF , then Convert that to HTML. There are many tools (including online tools) to achieve that [[2]] Why should it be HTML ? Why not PDF ? What is the End requirement ? Knowing that will help in getting more targeted answers !

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution, I have recently updated my Word docx to html converter to now recognise Mathematical Equations and display them correctly on a webpage. I use the online version of Mathjax to enable me to easily display maths equations on a web page. This is a simple php class which takes a docx file as its input and outputs it as html to display on a web page and/or save to a file.

I have only just added this facility, so there may still be some issues with it. If do find any I am very happy to look into them and rectify them for you.

For more info and to download my 'wordtohtml' php class, see either:
https://github.com/timy352/wordtohtml
or
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/12250-PHP-Convert-Microsoft-Word-DOCX-document-to-HTML.html